# .NET Core 1.1: Nuget unable to restore local package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.0, nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-community

I have a .NET core 1.1.2 app that package references to two other .NET core 1.1.2 apps. Here's my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="../DataAccess/DapperORM/DapperORM.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="../Models/Models.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.4.2" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It's able to restore the three packages near the bottom just fine, but cannot restore the two local ones near the top. I don't know why.

The exact error I get is:

```
Error   NU1101  Unable to find package 
../DataAccess/DapperORM/DapperORM.csproj. No packages exist with this id in 
source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Microsoft Visual 
Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org
```

The error appears for the Models.csproj as well. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 in Windows 10. In the VS Installer, under `ASP.NET and web development`, I have both `.NET Core 2.0 development tools` as well as `.NET Core 1.0 - 1.1 development tools for Web` installed. The same for the `.NET Core cross-platform development` category.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why you added the Core 1 and 2 tags? Choose the right one for your project. If your project is Core 1, it is highly recommended to upgrade to 2. Core 1 lacks tons of features and is not really recommended for a serious project.

Comment: @RacilHilan, this is an existing project that I am trying to restore, written by a different developer. I agree, upgrading to 2 would be ideal. However, this is a 1.1 app referencing other 1.1 apps. It's not my app and I can't upgrade it right now. This same problem was happening when I only had the tooling for 2 installed. I then went back to the installer and added the tooling for 1.x, and I'm still experiencing the exact same problem.

Comment: OK, but the tags are for your project, not the tools installed on your computer. I edited it for you.

Comment: @RacilHilan, oh, I see what you're saying, sorry about that, and thanks!